# Implications of communalities close to 1.00 for reliability analysis and survey design

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability

I was trying to do a test of reliability for my survey items. In addition to Cronbach's alpha I'm looking at communalities. My criteria is that survey items with communality below 0.4 will be dropped. But when I looked at my communality table, I saw that some items had .99 for communality. Is this problematic? What should I do with these?

Comment: How many factors did you extracted and what kind of rotation did you use, if any? Also, what is the number of items and the sample size?

Comment: I used varimax rotation, and four factors were extracted. Sample size was 104. I just found that my sample does not meet multivariate normality assumptions. Combined with low sample, this may have caused high communalities, I think. But I'm still not sure if these items can be retained or not. When I used principle component analysis for factor extraction, all communalities were below .9.

Answer (score 1):

With a sample size of 104, any factor analysis is going to be shaky at best. The best approach is probably to collect more data (not really that useful an answer, but its true). [This page](http://www.technion.ac.il/docs/sas/stat/chap26/sect21.htm) gives some useful advice.

[Fabrigar et al (1999)](http://www.statpower.net/Content/312/Handout/Fabrigar1999.pdf) indicate that large communalities can often lower the sample size required, but almost 1 is probably way too high. I would drop the offending items and re-run the analysis (using ML, principal axis and another method of your choice) and see what the results are. If they still produce heywood cases, then FA is probably not the right approach.